# how to customize positions using html in DW?

Tags: html, browser, dreamweaver

i'm making an application using DreamWaver by HTML, i'm making a new div and positioned it using the DreamWaver design capabilities, but when running it in the browser i found that the position had changed, it's in the following figures:

***IN DW:**

http://postimg.org/image/cvshkio0v/

***in browser(firefox & chrome):**

http://postimg.org/image/85ve2097f/

**and that's the code parts:**

#### CSS

```
.buttonClass {
    width: 320px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: normal;
    border-radius: 7px;
    z-index: 3;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#FFF 0%,#91BDD6 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #91BDD6 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#FFF,#91BDD6);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#FFF,#91BDD6);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top,#FFF,#91BDD6);
    border: solid #91BDD6 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px #fff, 5px 3px 12px #000000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 1014px;
    top: 591px;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div id="confirm" class="buttonClass">
  <div align="center">Confirm</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't rely on Dreamweaver preview, always code according to browser view and test your code in all major browsers.

Comment: i don't know how to adjust the div in that position using code as i'm new in that

Comment: Ok, play with this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/jdTBw/) ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because different browsers have different size

try right: 0; bottom: 0; in button class

and delete left: #; top: #;

you also dont need align center or the second div inside the div
because buttonClass css already define the position of the content by text-align: center;